# How to call fancybox out of flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, popup, fancybox

I want to use fancybox from inside flash.
I call a javascript function with

> var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:callPopup()"); 
>   navigateToURL(url, "_self");

and

> function callPopup(){ alert("works");}

which works fine.
now I want to use this function to open my fancybox content.

the flash content is placed with swfobject. under the flashcontent-div I have my link to the fancybox-content:

```
<div id="micrositepopup">
    <a id="popup" href="images/microsite/microsite.jpg">test</a>
</div>
```

and I call on pageload

> $(document).ready(function() {$("a#popup").fancybox();});

when I click on the test-link all works fine.
but how could I call the function

> function callPopup(){ $("a#popup").fancybox(); } // not working

to open the fabcybox with the linked content?
thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah - ok. you need to use

> function callPopup(){ $("a#popup").trigger("click");  }

;-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
you need to use: Jquery in Flash CS5 with Fancybox 
http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Photos_Graphics/Web_Graphics/Macromedia_Flash/ActionScript/Q_26325406.html